# ionic/cordova how to keep the Keyboard on the screen while input lost focus

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

Actually. I've tried this solution:

> focus on the input filed instantly when it lost focus.

but it cause the keyboard down and up. which is a bad experience for the user.

I want to do this mainly because i want to continuous deal with text in the input field by clicking a button. which causes the input filed lost focus.

anyone's help or comments are appreciated.
thanks a lot!

Comment: the solution i've used  ```$timeout(function () {
            document.querySelector("#text_content").focus();
          }, 0);```

Answer (score 0):

**It will work if you use the same code.
If it works, please vote it so that it can be useful to others.**

```
<ion-input #input placeholder="Type a message.." (blur)="input.focus()"></ion-input>
```